# Why Delegates are used in Tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, delegates

I am new to iOS, why did we use default delegates in tableview, when are they called. Where can i get to know the complete use of delegates in tableview

Comment: Please read up the documentation provided by Apple, including their guides. It's very detailed and worth every minute.

Comment: @Sowjanya lankisetty : You can get to know about all the delegates of tableView when you implement a tableView :) Please follow any of the UITableView tutorial either in swift or Objective C you will understand :)

Comment: Please refer  this "https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/"

Comment: Thanks for responses, sure will follow

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/ follow this you can understand much better, then see apple documentation you can get clear idae